# code coverage only 14% custom setting

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, customsetting

apex class:

```
public with sharing class sample
{
public sample(Assetcommunication_Max controller) {}
public string settings{get;set;}
public sample(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{

}
public string getAcceptFileNames()
{
    FileFilter__c settings = FileFilter__c.getvalues('Filterextension');
    system.debug('name is'+settings.FileType__c);
    string AcceptFileNames = settings.FileType__c;
    return AcceptFileNames;
}
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest(Seealldata=True)
public class sampletest
{
   static testMethod void samplemethodtest()
   {
        FileFilter__c ff = New FileFilter__c();
        ff.Name='test class name';
        ff.FileType__c = 'tetjgh';
         test.starttest();
        insert ff;   
        ApexPages.StandardController scc = new ApexPages.StandardController(ff);
        sample s = new sample(scc);
         test.stoptest(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Assetcommunication_Max`?

Comment: that is  visualforce page name

Comment: You could not pass vf page name as a type. Did you compile this class.

Comment: i removed that line setting variable. its working 83% covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this test class. Avoid using `seealldata=true`.

```
public class sampletest
{
   static testMethod void samplemethodtest()
   {
        FileFilter__c ff = New FileFilter__c();
        ff.Name='Filterextension';
        ff.FileType__c = 'Testtype';

        test.starttest();
        insert ff;   
        ApexPages.StandardController scc = new ApexPages.StandardController(ff);
        sample s = new sample(scc);

        System.assertEquals(ff.FileType__c, s.getAcceptFileNames(), 'Matched field type');
        test.stoptest(); 
    }
}
```

I am not sure why you need these two lines in sample class.

```
public sample(Assetcommunication_Max controller) {}
public string settings{get;set;}
```

Remove unwanted code for better code coverage.

Comment: Now 71% covered

Comment: @VelumaniV have you removed the unwanted code.

Comment: if i remove this line: public sample(Assetcommunication_Max controller) {}
  ,in vf page it is throwing error(unknown controller). settings variable is to pass value to vf page.

Comment: The syntax is `system.assertEquals(expected, observed, message)`. You have expectation and observation switched.

Comment: @AdrianLarson thanks for pointing out. Updated code.